# ASP.NET MVC Update fields of data Table at once

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have this view and I need to update the table Task upon the chosen values at Value Column [View: EstimateValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpAaW.png). The view accepts @model IEnumerable then iterate the list of tasks and display them in Table.

The View

```
@model IEnumerable<Task>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Value)           
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID)
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The Controller has the post method EstimateValue

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EstimateValue(IEnumerable<Task> TaskList)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var task in TaskList)
            {
                db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //1. Rebound List to view
        var TaskList = db.Tasks.ToList();
        //2, return model to view
        return View(TaskList);
    }
```

When running the application the TaskList is null and I could not update the table Task. I have used JSON to send the data from the view as an array but still the values of TaskList are null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your IEnumerable to List because IEnumerable does not allow indexing. And instead of @foreach loop, use @for loop. So your View should be like this:

```
@model List<Task>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model[0].Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model[0].Description)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model[0].Value)           
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for(int i=0;i<Model.Count;i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].ID)
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => modelItem[i].Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Then change your Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EstimateValue(List<Task> TaskList)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<TaskList.Count;i++)
            {
                db.Entry(TaskList[i]).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        //1. Rebound List to view
        var TaskList = db.Tasks.ToList();
        //2, return model to view
        return View(TaskList);
    }
```

If this solves your problem, accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after changing to List<> and for loop at the view. Thank you again

Comment: Question, why use a forloop instead of a foreach? wouldn't they both accomplish the same?